# virtual host in nginx not working

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I'm creating virtual host using `nginx` with following configuration:

```
server {
    listen       7001;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

When I trying access by `example.com` or `exemple.com:7001`, it is not working, but it is working when I access by `localhost:7001`, where is wrong in my configuration?

### Edit 1

I'm in `Windows` platform

### Edit 2

When I trying access by `example.com` or `example.com:7001`, it will access online `example.com` web site, or web site not found notification when access by `example.com:7001`

Comment: Do you have a firewall that blocks outside connections?

Comment: not have a firewall blocked, and I'm testing this in localhost, need I insert example.com in my hosts file?

Comment: Is exemplo.com (or example.com? which one do we use?) resolving to an ip that is configured on your machine? Take it step by step, check all the basic stuff.

Comment: Is "exemple.com", sorry my bad, I will check this step by step

Comment: Define/demonstrate "is not working"

Comment: @AD7six I updated my question, detailing problem

Comment: Is necessary insert 127.0.0.1 exemple.com  in my 'hosts' file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be sure that the DNS name *example.com* resolves to the IP address where nginx is running. In this case, it's your local IP address, so 127.0.0.1 would work.

Basically you need an entry in your HOSTS file like this:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) for instructions on how to edit your HOSTS file.

So that when you ping it or run *nslookup example.com*, it resolves to an IP address, specifically 127.0.0.1